# Trouble verifying a step in a proof regarding the span of an orthonormal family

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

I'm reading Sheldon Axler's Measure, Integration & Real Analysis and I am confused about a step that the reader is asked to verify. The theorem is:

> Suppose $\left\{e_k\right\}_{k \in \Gamma}$ is an orthonormal family in a Hilbert space $V$. Then
> $\overline{\text { span }\left\{e_k\right\}_{k \in \Gamma}}=\left\{\sum_{k \in \Gamma} \alpha_k e_k:\left\{\alpha_k\right\}_{k \in \Gamma}\right.$ is a family in $\mathrm{F}$ and $\left.\sum_{k \in \Gamma}\left|\alpha_k\right|^2<\infty\right\}$.

Then after proving  $\sum_{k \in \Gamma} \alpha_k e_k \in \overline{\operatorname{span}\left\{e_k\right\}_{k \in \Gamma}}$ the inclusion in the other direction starts:

> To prove the inclusion in the other direction, now suppose $f \in \overline{\operatorname{span}\left\{e_k\right\}_{k \in \Gamma}}$. Let
> $$
> (8.59) \;\;\;\;\;g=\sum_{k \in \Gamma}\left\langle f, e_k\right\rangle e_k,
> $$
> where the sum above converges by Bessel's inequality (8.57) and by $8.54(\mathrm{a})$. The
> direction of the inclusion that we just proved implies that $g \in \overline{\operatorname{span}\left\{e_k\right\}_{k \in \Gamma}}$. Thus
> $$
> (8.60) \;\;\;\;\;g-f \in \overline{\operatorname{span}\left\{e_k\right\}_{k \in \Gamma}} .
> $$
> **Equation 8.59 implies that $\left\langle g, e_j\right\rangle=\left\langle f, e_j\right\rangle$ for each $j \in \Gamma$, as you should verify (which will require using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality if done rigorously).**

I know that this verification can be shown by first proving the continuity of the inner product for unordered sums (which I assume requires using Cauchy Schwartz) however, I cant help but feel that there is a really obvious way of doing this that I am missing. So, if it exists, I would appreciate any help in pointing it out to me.

Comment: $|\langle u_n-u, v\rangle| \le \|u_n-u\|\|v\|$ proves that $\langle u_n, v\rangle \to \langle u, v\rangle$ when $u_n \to u$. And from that it follows that $$\langle g, e_i\rangle = \sum_k \langle f, e_k\rangle \langle e_k, e_i\rangle = \langle f, e_i\rangle$$ since $\langle e_k, e_i\rangle = \delta_{k,i}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $j \in \Gamma$. Let $\varepsilon \in (0, \infty )$. By the definition of convergence of an unordered sum, there exists a finite subset $F$ of $\Gamma$ with $j\in F$ such that

$$\left\| g - \sum_{k\in F}\langle f,e_{k}\rangle e_{k} \right\| < \varepsilon .$$

It can be directly verified that as $j\in F$ and as $\{e_{k} : k\in\Gamma \}$ is an orthonormal family,

$$\left\langle \sum_{k\in F}\langle f,e_{k}\rangle e_{k}, e_{j} \right\rangle = \langle f, e_{j} \rangle .$$

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

\begin{align*}
|\langle g,e_{j}\rangle - \langle f, e_{j}\rangle | &= \left|\left\langle g - \sum_{k\in F}\langle f,e_{k}\rangle e_{k}, e_{j} \right\rangle\right| \\ &\leq \left\| g - \sum_{k\in F}\langle f,e_{k}\rangle e_{k} \right\| \cdot \left\|e_{j}\right\| \\
& < \varepsilon .
\end{align*}

The result follows.